How to use Azure CLI to fetch API secrets from Azure Vault
using the RestAssured framework for API automation and have stored API IDs and passwords directly within our repository. I would like to enhance security by removing these credentials from the repository and storing them in Azure Key Vault instead.
Could you please guide me on how to use Azure CLI to retrieve API IDs and passwords from Azure Key Vault while running tests locally on my laptop and in the Azure pipeline?
Current Setup:
API tests include endpoints and POST request bodies.
I have added headers for the requests.
I plan to replace the API IDs and passwords with a variable {client-secret}.
Requirements:
How to configure the code to send a POST request using the {client-secret} variable.
Ensure that the {client-secret} variable fetches the API IDs and passwords from Azure Key Vault.
Thank you for your assistance!

Have you tried the "az keyvault secret download" command and the  AzureKeyVault@2 task as suggested in my answer below? Are they working for you?  @CharlotteRyerr

On you local machine, you can use the Azure CLI command "az keyvault secret download" to get the secret from Azure Key Vault. This command will save the secret value to a specified file that will be automatically created. Then you can read the value from the file for use in the subsequent command lines/scripts.
For example, I have two secrets (myUsername and myPassword) stored in Azure Key Vault.

On local machine, I can run the following command lines to download the values of the secrets.
az login
az keyvault secret download --vault-name BrightRanKV --name myUsername --file myUsername.txt
az keyvault secret download --vault-name BrightRanKV --name myPassword --file myPassword.txt


In Azure DevOps pipelines, there is the built-in task AzureKeyVault@2 can be used to download the secrets from Azure Key Vault.

In the Azure DevOps project where your pipeline is in, go to Project Settings > Service connections to create an Azure Resource Manager service connection (ARM connection) to the Azure Subscription where your Azure Key Vault is in.


Ensure the Service Principal used by the ARM connection has the Get and List for Secret permissions in the Azure Key Vault.


Then in the pipeline, you can use the ARM connection on the AzureKeyVault@2 task for authorization.
steps:
# Download the specified secrets from Azure KeyVault.
# The task will set the secrets as pipeline secret variables using the same secret names.
- task: AzureKeyVault@2
  displayName: 'Download Secrets from Azure KeyVault'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'ArmConnection'
    KeyVaultName: 'BrightRanKV'
    SecretsFilter: 'myUsername, myPassword'

# In the subsequent script tasks (such as bash, powershell, etc..),
# you need to map the secret variables as environment variables.
# Then you can call the environment variables in the scripts.
- bash: |
    echo "MY_USERNAME = $MY_USERNAME"
    echo "MY_PASSWORD = $MY_PASSWORD"
  env:
    MY_USERNAME: $(myUsername)
    MY_PASSWORD: $(myPassword)

- powershell: |
    echo "MY_USERNAME = ${env:MY_USERNAME}"
    echo "MY_PASSWORD = ${env:MY_PASSWORD}"
  env:
    MY_USERNAME: $(myUsername)
    MY_PASSWORD: $(myPassword)


Since the values are secrets, when you try to print the values in pipeline, for security reason, they will be always masked as '***' in the output logs. This is aiming to protect your sensitive information stored in the secrets.




Are the "az keyvault secret download" command and the AzureKeyVault@2 task working for you? @CharlotteRyerr

Hi There,
I need to try this Out by next Week.
here's my situation, I am going to store my username and password in azure library. I have been told to install azure cli and it has been authenticated. now I just want to update my tests and azure pipeline to extract credentials from azure library during the test execution

@CharlotteRyerr, What do you mean about "azure library"?
